# Simulating Leach has encounter a problem. Finished with error in omnet++

Tags: c++, omnet++

When running the simulation in omnet++ 5.7 the execution stops suddenly and closes.
This is the code that is being run in omnet

```
auto simulation = getSimulation();
for (i = 1; i <= simulation->getLastComponentId(); i++) {

    int x, y, id;

    //scan the simulation module vector
    mod = (cModule*)simulation->getModule(i);

    if (strcmp(mod->getName(), "node") == 0) {
        id = ((Node*)mod)->myId;
        x = ((Node*)mod)->xpos;
        y = ((Node*)mod)->ypos;
        nodePtr[id] = ((Node*)mod);

        if (id != this->myId) {
            cGate* g;
            char gName1[32], gName2[32];

            // make new gate here
            if (this->hasGate(gName1)) {
                this->gate(gName1)->disconnect();
                this->deleteGate(gName1);
            }

            this->addGate(gName1, cGate::OUTPUT, false);

            // make new gate at other side
            if (mod->hasGate(gName2)) {
                mod->gate(gName2)->disconnect();
                mod->deleteGate(gName2);
            }

            mod->addGate(gName2, omnetpp::cGate::INPUT, false);

            //CHANNEL
            cIdealChannel* ch = NULL;
            this->gate(gName1)->connectTo(mod->gate(gName2), ch);
            g = this->gate(gName1);
            g->setDisplayString(g->getDisplayString());
        }
    }
}
```

I assume that the last line  `g->setDisplayString(g->getDisplayString());` is probably where the code breaks. The code repeats in the for loop with `i<= simulation->getLastComponentId()`. I'm new to Omnet++. Any suggestion to fix this would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Starting with 1 up to N is uncommon in C/C++. Are you sure it is not from 0 to N-1???

Comment: @U.W. yeah, I think so

Comment: And the IDs are consecutive without any gaps? Just wondering...

Comment: Well, run it in a debugger and see where it crashes and how the stack trace looks like. That should tell you everything you need, unless you want to sprinkle some printf() around.

Answer (score 0):

Several things in your code may be source of crashing:

1. `getModule(i)` may return `nullptr`, see [OMNeT++ Simulation API](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cSimulation.html#a4ca7929dc35933f1605becdf1f241023), so you should check in the code whether result is not `nullptr`.
2. `gName1` and `gName2` are not set!

Other issues:

- instead of `(Node*)mod` use `dynamic_cast<Node*)>(mod)` and check whether results is not `nullptr`.
- instead of `strcmp(mod->getName(), "node") == 0` I advice using `mod->isName("node")` - see [OMNeT++ Simulation API](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cObject.html#a3666b57e313a2f38433fdfc50fd94a6b)
- if you want to obtain a module whose name is "node", you do not need to manually check the name of every module - there is a useful method `getModuleByPath()` see  [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:finding-modules-by-path)